# How to insert/update SQLite Database in Android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-database, android-sql

I am using the SQLite database to save some information locally. I want to update the row with the same userID each time while saving new data for that particular userID. But it should insert the data to a new row with the new userID and insertion should work the first time also.
Appreciate the help!

Comment: are you using room database? at least add some code snippet that you have tried so that we can help you with that

Comment: @unownsp no i am using SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code for update data for a specific row

```
    val db = this.writableDatabase
    val values = ContentValues()
    values.put(TITLE, tasks.title)
    values.put(EMAIL, tasks.email)
    values.put(PWD, tasks.pwd)
    val success = db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "$ID=?", arrayOf(id)).toLong()
    db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using room database you can insert/update as follow:

```
AppDatabase appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(Activity.this, AppDatabase.class, "db_name")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();

            DatabaseItems databaseItems = new DatabaseItems();
            databaseItems.setId(userID);
            databaseItems.setName(name);//set other needed data

            try {
                appDatabase.getDatabaseItemDAO().insertItem(databaseItems);

                Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                
                Log.d("TAG", "onClick: =======================> added");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                appDatabase.getDatabaseItemDAO().updateItem(databaseItems);

                Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                
                Log.d("TAG", "onClick: ==========================> updated");
            }
```

in this logic if your database already has a item with the id then updateItem will be called in 'catch'

you database item DAO should look something like this:

```
@Dao
public interface DatabaseItemsDAO {
    @Insert
    void insertItem(DatabaseItems databaseItems);

    @Update
    void updateItem(DatabaseItems databaseItems);
}
```